# What happens if a sender changes the TCP window size over multiple packets that have the same ACK number?

Tags: ids, tcp, attack-vector, header

I'm currently doing research on evasion attacks that seek to bypass a Deep-learning based Network Intrusion Detection System.

In order to achieve this, I need to know what the constraints are for the TCP window size field in the TCP packet header. Imagine a client has just sent the last TCP-ACK packet to a server in order to complete the 3-way handshake. He then immediately proceeds to send a GET request to the server (these 2 packets are thus sent one after the other, and contain the same ACK-number).

What happens if the TCP window size in the TCP-ACK packet does not match the window size in the TCP packet containing the GET request? Will the receiver simply observe the last value for the window size that he obtained? Or will there be a violation in the TCP protocol in any way? You can assume that the change in window size is very small, and will not cause the buffer to be full.

More generally, if the client sends N uninterrupted packets (e.g. a heavy-load POST request), can he change the window size in each packet header without repercussions?

Comment: This is not a security question - even if you want to use the answer in a security related context. It is a pure network question and should be better asked at [networkengineering.se].

Comment: I guess I'll just have to give up then, since I originally posted my question [there](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68767/what-happens-if-a-sender-changes-the-tcp-window-size-over-packets-it-sends-one-a) and got referred to this place. But it's alright, the question was so specific that I doubt many would know the answer to it, so I'm ready to give up.

Comment: I think the question has different interpretations and it is not clear what you actually ask. If you want to know how it should behave it is not a security question and the standard (as pointed out by comments at [networkengineering.se]) should give you the answer. If the question is instead on how systems behave in reality and if this can be used to bypass security systems then it is on-topic here. So it might be the best to focus on the aspect you are actually interested in and ask exactly this aspect and nothing else at the  suitable site.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. The focus of my question indeed lies more with how a system would behave in reality, and whether I could get away with deviating off the "standard", which is to keep the 'window size' header the same as long as the ACK number is the same. (The TCP standard unfortunately didn't cover this).

However, this is so deep into the research side of things (as it is part of a Master thesis) that it might not be fully on-topic here either, especially since it takes place in a simulated environment. Anyway, thank you for your time!